# Is there any difference between `git merge origin master` and `git merge origin/master`?

Tags: git, git-merge

Can any body explain the difference between `git merge origin master` and `git merge origin/master`?

I did accidentally did `git merge origin master`.  If it is different, what is the command to reset that merge?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After my test, `$git merge origin master` equals `$git merge origin/HEAD master`.

This means merge two branch (origin/HEAD, master) into current branch, which is very different from `$git merge origin/master`.

But as usually, master branch and origin/HEAD is in the same commit line, so these two command performs the same.

And I try the case in which master and origin/HEAD diverged, the result shown as the following with `$git merge origin master`:

```
*-.   33f82cd (HEAD, test) merge
|\ \  
| | * 46d0c92 (master) 22
| * | 9d9f51c (origin/test, origin/HEAD) 11
| |/  
* | 5ecfebd (origin/master) modify 2.txt
|/  
* 14949b6 remove 1.txt
```

Comment: Ah yes, the DWIM (do what I mean) in action again, converting the `origin` into a commit reference by assuming you want it's HEAD, and again assuming/finding that `origin` is one of your remotes. It also shows the effect of that space.

Comment: git merge origin/master merges remote into the local one?