# Git Merge with and without slash

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I have a question about merging your master/development branch back into your feature/working branch in git.  Can someone please explain what (if any) the difference is in the following commands.  My branch has been branched from development and I want to updated it with the latest development changes.

```
git merge origin development
git merge origin/development
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243569/is-there-any-difference-between-git-merge-origin-master-and-git-merge-origin) helps you to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`git-merge` manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge):

> ```
> git merge [-n] [--stat] [--no-commit] [--squash] [--[no-]edit]
>   [-s <strategy>] [-X <strategy-option>] [-S[<keyid>]]
>   [--[no-]allow-unrelated-histories]
>   [--[no-]rerere-autoupdate] [-m <msg>] [<commit>…​]
> ```
>
> …
>
> `<commit>…`
>   Commits, usually other branch heads, to merge into our branch.
>
> Specifying more than one commit will create a merge with more than two
>   parents (affectionately called an Octopus merge).

---

```
git merge origin development
```

This would merge the *two commits* specified by `origin` and `development` (in this case this would be the names of branches<sup>1</sup>) into your current branch.

```
o--o     origin
    \
o--o \   development
    \ |
     \|
o--o--o  your-branch
```

This is probably not what you want (I presume you don't even have a branch called `origin`).

<sup>(1)</sup> Unless you have a remote called `origin` (which is likely), then `origin` will be interpreted as the remote reference `origin/HEAD`.

---

```
git merge origin/development
```

This would merge the *single commit* specified by `origin/development` (which is a [*remote reference*](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References)) into your current branch.

```
o--o     origin/development
    \
     \
o--o--o  your-branch
```

Comment: While this seems to accurately reflect what the documentation says, observed behavior is different.  Having no `origin` branch (but an `origin` remote) I can do `git merge origin` and it does *not* error out (as it would if the above explanation were complete).  I don't have an explanation for this yet, only observed behavior.  I assume it means that git has some defined way of interpreting a remote name as a reference

Comment: And the answer appears in the question's comments: `origin` as a ref apparently means `origin/HEAD`